# How to reverse Fragment Transaction with Back button on a Media Controller?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, mediacontroller, onbackpressed

I am trying to reverse a fragment transaction to bring the user back to the previous fragment when the user hits the back button. Problem is, there is a media controller and so, the back button event will be handled by dispatchKeyEvent.I've tried to manually call onBackPressed as follows but I receive a null pointer exception.

```
MainActivity obj;

  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        obj = new MainActivity();
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            System.out.println(obj);
            obj.onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

In my main activity, my fragment transaction is as follows:

```
            transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

What is the best way that I can handle the back button to involve reversing the fragment transaction and the MediaController?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Override this method of fragment to get the reference of the activity object

```
MainActivity obj;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    obj = (MainActivity) obj;    
}
```

Remove the object creation in `dispatchKeyEvent()`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it flags me an error saying cannot resolve method onAttach. Do I declare this method in the MediaController Class or Main Activity?

Comment: @LewWeiHao declare this in fragment.